# Capturing only Incoming call in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I am creating an app and need to capture the Incoming calls only. I am using BroadCast class and Phone Listener class for this and in the PhoneListnere class capturing whether there is incoming call or not. My problem is that i do not want my app to get trigerred if there is any outgoing call. My broadcast class gets trigger even if there is any outgoing call (though i am neatly exiting the app for the outgoing calls) but not liking the idea that the app is actually getting trigerred. Is there any specific Intent just to handle the Incoming calls?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED) intent, and store the last state. If the current state is `TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK`, a call exists that is dialing, active or on hold. If the previous state was RINGING then this is an incoming call. If the previous state was IDLE, then this is an outgoing call.

The following receiver distinguishes different scenarios:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
    if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
        // Device call state: Ringing. A new call arrived and is ringing or waiting. In the latter case, another call is already active.
        String incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
    }else if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK){
        // Device call state: Off-hook. At least one call exists that is dialing, active, or on hold, and no calls are ringing or waiting.
        if(lastState.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE){
            // outgoing call                
        } else if(lastState.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING){
            // incoming call
        }
    }else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){
        // Device call state: No activity.
    }
    lastState = state;
}
```

Comment: <receiver android:name="com.droidapps.callspeaker.Speaker" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />      
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>.....This is my manifest and i am using intent which you mentioned but this gets triggered even if you make an outgoing call. The android site also says that it detects the change in the phone state. My intention is that my app shouldn't be trigerred if there is any outgoing call.

Comment: Hm, this seems to be triggered for outgoing calls as well indeed. What you can do is also register a receiver for the `android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL` intent. When that happens, store some kind of variable. In the onReceive() of the `ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED` intent you can then check if the outgoing happened shortly before or not.

Comment: Update: another solution that seems to work is to set the last state in onReceive(); I updated my answer with that code.

Comment: yes got your point but seems there is no solution (atleast i couldn't figure out) for handling incoming calls. If there is any outgoing call the app gets triggered (i understand and thanks) that you (Jeff) has provided a solution for it.